# Hello world /tmp/cctL3Ti2.o: file not recognized: File truncated collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, compilar

¿Como soluciono ese error cuando compilo archivos .cpp con el comando `g++ file_name.cpp`?

Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "hola" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: lo dice arriba g++ nombreArchivo.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Borra el archivo:

```
/tmp/cctL3Ti2.o
```

Y después recompila.

Tiene toda la pinta que ese archivo se ha generado con otro compilador o una versión de g++ incompatible con la versión actual (más moderna o más antigua) o simplemente ha sido el resultado de una compilación que se ha interrumpido y el fichero está, simplemente, corrupto.